# #500 Fatal Error при первичном запросе

Tags: php

После переноса со старого хостинга на новый, при попытке "отправить в корзину" любое содержимое каталога на dkm-k.ru, при определенном запросе всплывает окно, в котором при первичном запросе появляется ошибка 500. После обновления страницы всё срабатывает.

**error.log** выдает следующую ошибку

> dkm-k.ru [Sat Dec 26 06:32:03 201] [error] [client 46.188.41.33] PHP
>   Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_unregister() in
>   /home/srv66045/htdocs/includes/shopping_cart.php on line 33, referer:
>   http://dkm-k.ru/index.php?categoryID=80

и потом пестрит вот такими.

> dkm-k.ru [Sat Dec 26 06:32:04 201] [error] [client 46.188.41.33] PHP
>   Notice: Undefined index: hack in
>   /home/srv66045/htdocs/core_functions/setting_functions.php(146) :
>   eval()'d code on line 1 dkm-k.ru [Sat Dec 26 06:32:04 201] [error]
>   [client 46.188.41.33] PHP Strict Standards: Only variables should be
>   passed by reference in
>   /home/srv66045/htdocs/smarty/smarty_compiler.class.php on line 804

по-первой ошибке (скорее всего в ней суть) код:

```
    if ( isset($_GET["add2cart"]) && $_GET["add2cart"]>0 /*&& isset($_SESSION["variants"]) */) 
{
    if (isset($_SESSION["variants"]))
    {
        $variants=$_SESSION["variants"];
        unset($_SESSION["variants"]);
        session_unregister("variants"); //calling session_unregister() is required since unset() may not work on some systems
    }
    else
    {
        $variants = array();
    }
    cartAddToCart( $_GET["add2cart"], $variants );
    Redirect( $cart_php_file."?shopping_cart=yes" );
}
```

Comment: а версия php какая? session_unregister [удалена в PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-unregister.php) По второй ошибке надо код смотреть, а последняя - надо файл smarty_compiler.class.php править на строчке 804 (вроде достаточно сделать, чтобы через переменную передавали параметр)

Comment: 5.3.27,
второй код длинный слишком,
а в третьем строка 804 имеет вид  `$_cache_attrs = ''; `

Comment: Приведите отрывок кода с 800 строки до 810 как минимум или в пределах функции

Answer (score 4):

```
        if ( isset($_GET["add2cart"]) && $_GET["add2cart"]>0 /*&& isset($_SESSION["variants"]) */) 
{
    if (isset($_SESSION["variants"]))
    {
        $variants=$_SESSION["variants"];
        unset($_SESSION["variants"]);
     //   session_unregister("variants"); //calling session_unregister() is required since unset() may not work on some systems
    }
    else
    {
        $variants = array();
    }
    cartAddToCart( $_GET["add2cart"], $variants );
    Redirect( $cart_php_file."?shopping_cart=yes" );
}
```

можно просто закоментировать а вот с eval Undefined index: hack это скорее всего какой то backdor судя по индексу hack

Comment: я внес изменения, но проблема не исчезла

Comment: @Alex На что теперь ругается?

Comment: Спасибо, всё не ругается. Решил вопрос сменой версии PHP на более раннюю